# Predicted lines for model with multiple explanatory variables on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, transformation, predict

My question is the following of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506201/re-transform-a-linear-model-case-study-with-r) I asked some hours ago. Looking at this post will help a lot understanding the question that follows.

I make a model with 1 response variable and 2 explanatory variables, one of them being a factor.

In my model, the response variable is transformed. I'd like to display on a graph my variables but I want the explanatory variable not to be transformed. Moreover I'd like to add the predicted line given by my model which for this purpose should be back-transformed! And to add one more slight difficulty I'd like to do it on a ggplot.

My question is **how can I extend [@Roland's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506201/re-transform-a-linear-model-case-study-with-r) to ggplot and to several explanatory variables?**

Here is an example:

set.seed(12)

```
resp = (rnorm(120)+20)^3.79
expl1 = rep(c(1,2,3,4),30)
expl2 = rep(1:3,40)
df = data.frame(resp=resp,expl1=expl1,expl2=expl2)

m=lm(resp~expl1*factor(expl2), data=df)
ggplot(data=df,aes(y=resp,x=expl1,shape=factor(expl2)))+geom_point() + geom_smooth(se=F)
```

Instead of the lines that are displayed I'd like to have the predicted values of my model after back-transformation. I could add `method='lm', formula =resp~expl1*factor(expl2)` in `geom_smooth` but whether I transform or not `resp`I will the same problem. Either the line does not fit because transformed, or it doesn't correspond to my model.

Hope my question makes sense! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `predict` with more than one explanatory variable much like how it was used in the answer to your previous question.  Then you simply need to back-transform your predictions to the original scale.  The predictions are in a different data.frame, so if I use `ggplot` I usually map the plot with the original data.frame and add the points, then draw the lines using the data.frame of predictions.

```
# A transformed response
df$resp2 = df$resp^(1/3.79)

m2 = lm(resp2 ~ expl1 * expl2, data=df)

plotexpl = seq(1, 4, by = .1)
# Use expand grid to make dataset for predictions
newdat = expand.grid(expl1 = plotexpl, expl2 = c("1", "2", "3"))
newdat$pred = predict(m2, newdata = newdat)

# Back-transform predictions
newdat$back = newdat$pred^3.79

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = expl1, y = resp, color = expl2)) +
    geom_point() + geom_line(data = newdat, aes(y = back) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to live with a base graphics solution instead of ggplot2 then the `Predict.Plot` function in the TeachingDemos package will plot predicted relationships between one of the predictors and the response at values of the other predictors and combine these plots to show multiple conditionings.  To get the proper transformation/back transformation of the response it may be better to use `glm` with a link function rather than `lm`.

If you need a ggplot2 solution then you could still use `Predict.Plot` as a starting point and adapt it to ggplot2.